# python multiple entry with screen keyboard

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make some entry with the button but I have to use Key to first make a interraction to entry widget. I want to make it without it and also but the problem is when you make multiple entry is there any way to choose that entry with mause click and cursor?
here is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import*
import sys

pencere = Tk()
#pencere.overrideredirect(1)#başlıksız pencere
boyut = pencere.geometry ("400x400+250+150")#x*y +x+y boyut ve konum
baslik = pencere.title("guc hesaplama programi") #pencere başlığı
say=0
def click(key):
   global  say
   if say==0:
      if key == 'C':
        joule_entry.delete(0, END)  # clear entry
    else:
        joule_entry.insert(END, key)
    if say==1:
       if key == 'C':
        time_entry.delete(0, END)  # clear entry
    else:
        time_entry.insert(END, key)
    if say==2:
        if key == 'C':
        power_entry.delete(0, END)  # clear entry
    else:
        power_entry.insert(END, key)
def write_joule():
   global  say
   say=0

def write_time():
    global  say
    say=1

def write_power():
    global  say
    say=2

def joule_find():
    joule_entry.delete(0,END)
    power_t = power_entry.get()
    power = float(power_t)
    time_t = time_entry.get()
    time = float(time_t)

    joule = time*power/1000

    if 0 <= power <= 1500 and 0 <= time <= 9999:  #sınırlamalarımız

        joule_entry.insert(0,str(round(joule,3)))

    else:
        joule_entry.insert(0,"error")

def time_find():
    time_entry.delete(0,END)
    power_t = power_entry.get()
    power = float(power_t)
    joule_t = joule_entry.get()
    joule = float(joule_t)

    time = joule/(power/1000)

    if 0 <= power <= 1500 and 0 <= time <= 9999:  #sınırlamalarımız

        time_entry.insert(0,str(round(time,3)))

    else:
        time_entry.insert(0,"error")

def power_find():
   power_entry.delete(0,END)
   joule_t = joule_entry.get()
   joule = float(joule_t)
   time_t = time_entry.get()
   time = float(time_t)

   guc = 1000*joule/time

   if 0 <= guc <= 1500 and 0 <= time <= 9999:  #sınırlamalarımız

       power_entry.insert(0,str(round(guc,3)))

   else:
       power_entry.insert(0,"error")

joule_button = Button(text="ENERGY\t:" ,font="arial 14 bold", command =     joule_find)    #
joule_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=10)         

joule_entry = Entry()
joule_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10,sticky="news")

joule_button2 = Button(text="key" ,font="arial 14 bold", command = write_joule)    #
joule_button2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="w", pady=10)

joule_label = Label(text="Joule" ,font="arial 14 bold")
joule_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w", pady=10)

time_button = Button(text="TIME\t:",font="arial 14 bold", command = time_find )
time_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", pady=10)

time_entry= Entry()
time_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10,sticky="news")

time_button2 = Button(text="key",font="arial 14 bold", command = write_time )
time_button2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="w", pady=10)

time_label= Label(text="Second",font="arial 14 bold" )
time_label.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")

power_button = Button(text="Power\t:",font="arial 14 bold", command = power_find )
power_button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w", pady=10)

power_entry= Entry()
power_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10,sticky="news")

power_button2 = Button(text="key",font="arial 14 bold", command = write_power )
power_button2.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="w", pady=10)

power_label= Label(text="milli Watt",font="arial 14 bold" )
power_label.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")

close = Button(text = "CLOSE",command = pencere.destroy)
close.grid(row=40,column=2,sticky="news")





btn_list = [
'7',  '8',  '9',
'4',  '5',  '6',
'1',  '2',  '3',
'0',  '.',  'C',]

# create all buttons with a loop
r = 5
c = 0

for b in btn_list:
   rel = 'ridge'
   cmd = lambda x=b: click(x)
   Button(text=b,width=5,relief=rel,command=cmd).grid(row=r,column=c,sticky="news")


c += 1
if c > 2:
    c = 0
    r += 1

mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please explain your question better? I can't understand it.

Comment: I will make a program. but I need to use screen keyboard. and every time I click in entry box I want program to open screen keyboard. But with multiple entry box if you make screeen keyboard it write in the first entry box even if you clicked the other entry box.